# How to list a file and execute in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the file names in a directory which are exe and then execute them one by one:

```
$files = get-childitem mydirectory

foreach ($file in $files)
{
     $file /s
}
```

But somehow the powershell is not liking this - it is complaining about the "/s". The $file contains valid file name which I checked against Write-Host. Now how to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Seems you have missed the call operator `&`

```
$files = get-childitem -Filter *.exe folder
foreach ($file in $files)
{
     &$file.Fullname /s
}
```

But you can also use `start-process`

```
$files = get-childitem -Filter *.exe folder
foreach ($file in $files)
{
     Start-Process $file.Fullname -ArgumentList "/s"
}
```